# Submit form if field is empty - jQuery Validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Hi I have a multiple forms on the page all of which have a hidden field which has a class called field that is set by default as empty in the html, we seem to be getting a lot of spam so my plan is if any data is entered into the hidden field the form doesn't submit but if its left blank then it submits, however it is stopping the regular user from submitting the form. I have tried this in jQuery:

```
jQuery('.form').each(function(e) {
        if (jQuery('input.field', this).val()) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {                
            jQuery(this).validate({
               rules: {
                 'last_name': {
                    required: true
                 },
                 'email': {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                 },
                 'phone': {
                    minlength: 9,
                    required: true
                 },
                 '00N580000026FkW': {
                    required: true
                 },
                 'emailOptOut': {
                    required: true
                 }
              }

           });

        }

    });
```

I have also tried this:

```
jQuery('.form').each(function() {

        var form = this;

            jQuery(this).validate({
               rules: {
                 'last_name': {
                    required: true
                 },
                 'email': {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                 },
                 'phone': {
                    minlength: 9,
                    required: true
                 },
                 '00N580000026FkW': {
                    required: true
                 },
                 'emailOptOut': {
                    required: true
                 }
              },
              submitHandler: function (form, event) {
                    if (jQuery('input.field', this).val()) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    } else {
                        form.submit();
                    }
                }

           });


    });
```

this is the html for the field:

```
<input id="00N5800000DA3Fk" maxlength="50" name="00N5800000DA3Fk" size="20" type="text" class="field" value="" />
```

Comment: This is a waste of time. The spam isn't coming from people using the form, it's coming from automated bots. They don't use your Javascript.

Comment: Just check the field on the server, don't do it on the client.

Comment: Sadly the website uses salesforce so I can't check the field on the server and thus why I need a client side solution and I know the spam is coming from the form completing every field they see however my plan is to leave the field by default empty and if filled then it doesn't submit.

Comment: Users can't fill in a hidden field. That's why it has to be coming from bots.

Comment: I know that and thats the reason why I am adding a hidden field, because if the hidden field is filled the form shouldn't submit.

Comment: So you shouldn't put `required: true` on the hidden field. That's what's preventing ordinary users from submitting the form. You'll need to write a custom validation method that does the opposite of `required`.

Comment: Why are you calling `e.preventDefault()` in your loop?  It's not an event handler, and `e` isn't an event (it's the index of the element).

Comment: the hidden field isn't included in the rules, I have amended the question though to include the html for the hidden field, in regards to your other question I was trying many different things mostly from what I found online prior to coming here.

Comment: Barmar is right in his first comment.  If you want to use a "honeypot" spam-trap, this is achieved on the server-side and never using JavaScript.